# How to route locally initiated traffic to different Gateway than NATted traffic?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, iptables, nat

I want to route all traffic that is "locally generated" on my router through a different interface/to ad different Gateway (VPN) than all traffic that is NATted through the machine.

Any ideas how this can be achieved?
I thought about marking the packages with iptables but I assume there is a simpler solution?

Answer (score 0):

It worked out like that:

```
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface tun0 -j MASQUERADE

echo 10 vpn >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add from 192.168.2.0/24 lookup vpn
ip route add default via 192.168.2.1 table vpn
```

192.168.2.1 is the local gateway I want to route through, 192.168.2.X my local net.